# Cassandra supported data types in maps

Tags: cassandra, cql

According to [CQL documentation](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/cql/cql_using/use_map_t.html) of maps:

> ... specifying the map collection and
>   enclosing the pair of data types in angle brackets.

Are there any unsupported data types/pairs in a map? Can we have any key/value datatype, including time_uuids for example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, any cql supported data types that are not collection types will work as the key value pair. The example in [this documentation](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/cql/cql_using/use_map_t.html) uses a timestamp-text as key-value pair